# Failed to authenticate with public key in jenkins

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, jenkins

I have two different servers:

1. Jenkins
2. EC2 instance (my vuejs application)

So When I am trying to deploy vuejs application using Jenkins SSH Plugin to remote server

but it can't connect

The log :

```
[SSH] executing...
ERROR: Failed to authenticate with public key
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@482626ec
```

[image]
  Private Key (dev.pem file content)
[image]
I can't figure out what is wrong.

So when i try connect by command line:

```
ssh -i dev.pem ec2-user@ec2-ip -p 22
```

It connected. 
Please help me, What should I do ?

Comment: Does the first line of the stored credential start "-----BEGIN OPENSSH" or was that line omitted when cutting and pasting?

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue in the ticket and solved.

> https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-57495

The problem is private key file format.

It related to the private key header. This is from ssh-keygen on Macbook, not from puttygen.Jenkins and plugin failed to read this format.
So , I have generated new pem file. It working fine to connect EC2 server

The private key looks like as below :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIE....
```